# How to draw shapes in WP7 with the finger?

Tags: windows-phone-7, drawing, paint

How to draw shapes in WP7 with the finger? I am trying to implement a simple paint application but I am not sure how to make the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fingerpaint is your friend

- try it out on Ruby using http://script.iron7.com/#/Script/Detail?scriptId=FingerPaint&userLowerCaseName=iron7
- or in C# at http://sigurdsnorteland.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/fingerpaint-a-little-wp7-paint-app/

[image: FingerPaint]

Note that the two sets of code aren't quite the same - the C# fingerpaint had some issues about drawing new tracks on top of old ones so I modified this when I wrote the Ruby one.

Also note that to take this further, you should probably support multitouch.

Answer (score 2):

There are two examples for you, you can download it from the below links.

[Sample Project 1](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger)

[Sample Project 2](http://fingerpaint.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line.aspx) Handle the StylusDown, StylusMove, and StylusUp events.  Draw lines as appropriate depending on if you want straight vs. free form lines.

Comment: I know about the Line class. What I am asking is how to handle the dynamic drawing with the finger!